# expressのルーティングでurlに変数を入れた時のファイルの分け方

Tags: node.js

```
app.use('/users',users);
router.get('/:user', function(req, res, next) {
```

を使ってルーティングするのはできるんですが、`/users/:user/`以下が増えた時のためにファイルを分けておきたいのですが

```
app.use('/users/:user',users);
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
```

だと`req.params.user`でパラメーターが取得できなくて困ってます
どう解決すればいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

`:id`などの位置で`Router`を分けたとき、子供`Router`のファイル側で`req.params.id`などとして受け取るということですね。

[Express 4.xのドキュメント](http://expressjs.com/ja/api.html#express.router)によると`Router`生成時に`express.Router({ mergeParams: true })`とすると親のRouterの変数を引き継げるようです。

ですのでclenousさんの例ですと
`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {`
がかいてある側のファイルの`router`を`express.Router({ mergeParams: true })`で生成する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

私はこのようにしています。

メインのファイル app.js には以下のように定義し、

```
const app = require("express")()
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"))
```

/users 以下を扱う users.js ファイルを作ります。users.js では次のように router を定義します

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/:user', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
}

module.exports = router
```

こうしておくと `/users/12345` にアクセスすると req.params.user で `12345` が取得できます。

router が増えても以下のように分かりやすい構造になります。

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"))
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"))
app.use("/ranking", require("./routes/ranking"))
app.use("/bookmarks", require("./routes/bookmarks"))
```